# Solve for positive $x$

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

Let $x>0$ be real. Find all solutions of $x^{0.3} = \ln x $ or more general equation $x^a= \ln x$ , where $ 0 < a < 1 $.

Comment: By taking $\ln$, this equation becomes $0.3 \ln x = \ln(\ln x)$ : it seems that it's impossible to find an analytic solution.

Comment: I don't know any analytical solutions.  If numerical ones are ok, then you are looking for fixed points of the function $f(x) = \sqrt[\alpha]{\ln x}$ (or of a suitable local inverse, if that's more convenient).

Comment: I don't think it is easy to express in terms of elementary functions. if $a=1$ you could use the W function.

Comment: WolframAlpha gives two solutions with Productlog function and its analytic continuation. One is $x = e^{\frac{-10}{3}W(-.3)}$ and $ x = e^{-\frac{10}{3}W_{1}(-.3)}$, where $W(z)$ is the product log function and $W_k(z)$ is the analytic continuation of product log function.

Answer (score 4):

Solutions of $x^a = \ln(x)$ are $(-W(-a)/a)^{1/a}$ where $W$ is a branch of the [Lambert W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function).  In the case $a= 3/10$, there are two real solutions
(corresponding to the principal and $-1$ branches of Lambert W), approximately 
$5.110722365$ and $379.0962301$.

EDIT: There are two real solutions if $0 < a < 1/e$, one if $a < 0$, and none if $a > 1/e$.

Comment: Thank you. Could you please write the solution with more explanations ?

Comment: Physicist137 explained it well.

Answer (score 4):

Lets solve it:

$$
x^a = \ln x \\
e^{x^a} = x \\
x = e^{x^a} \\
x^a = e^{a x^a} \\
a x^a = a e^{a x^a} \\
a x^a e^{-a x^a} = a \\
-a x^a e^{-a x^a} = -a
$$

Let $s = -a x^a $. We then have the equation:
$$
s e^s = -a
$$

Thus we can solve for $s$ if we say: $s = W(a)$, where $W$ is the inverse function of $f(s) = s e^s$, that is, $W = f^{-1}$, also called, [Lambert-W Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function). Be careful, there are two branchs in the real domain.

Therefore, we can now continue:
$$
-a x^a = W\left(-a\right)
$$

Thus:
$$
x^a = -\frac{1}{a} W\left(-a\right)
$$